# How to convert XML Text and insert into Microsoft SQL Server using a stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, stored-procedures, soap

I have a XML file like this:

```
<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap=\"http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope\" 
               xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" 
               xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\">
    <soap:Body>
        <Abc ">
            <Def>ID&gt;1&lt;/ID&gt;&lt;Number&gt;Not Available&lt;/Number&gt;&lt;AbcName&gt;Hello&lt;/AbcName&</Def>
        </Abc>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I want to write a stored procedure that extracts the text inside the `DEF` tag and get column data like Id, abcname and insert into a SQL Server database.

Any help in this issue will be greatly appreciated.

Thank You!

Comment: That's a whole lot of not-valid XML there. What's with all the backslash characters and the lone `&` character? As a starting point you should talk to your data supplier about producing valid XML so you've got something to work with.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning Hi thanks for your response this is the response of a soap api i am getting and this is the data i have to extract using proceudure and insert into table

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that the XML nodes inside `Def` are not encoded properly. They are stored as inner text within the node. So you need to pull it out and convert it.

We can pull out the text using `.value` and the `CAST` it, inside a `CROSS APPLY (VALUES`.

You can either do this using direct `.value` calls

```sql
DECLARE @xml xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" 
               xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
               xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <soap:Body>
        <Abc xmlns="http://www.web.xds.co.za/XDSConnectWS">
            <Def>&lt;ID&gt;1&lt;/ID&gt;&lt;Number&gt;Not Available&lt;/Number&gt;&lt;AbcName&gt;Hello&lt;/AbcName&gt;</Def>
        </Abc>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>';

WITH XMLNAMESPACES(
  'http://www.web.xds.co.za/XDSConnectWS' AS x,
  'http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope' AS soap
)
SELECT
  v.InnerXml.value('(ID/text())[1]','int') as ID,
  v.InnerXml.value('(AbcName/text())[1]','varchar(30)') as Name,
  v.InnerXml.value('(Number/text())[1]','varchar(30)') as Number
FROM (VALUES(
    CAST(@xml.value('(soap:Envelope/soap:Body/x:Abc/x:Def/text())[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS xml)
)) v(InnerXml);
```

Or if you have multiple nodes to read then you can feed it through `.nodes`:

```sql
WITH XMLNAMESPACES(
  'http://www.web.xds.co.za/XDSConnectWS' AS x,
  'http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope' AS soap
)
SELECT
  x2.n.value('(ID/text())[1]','int') as ID,
  x2.n.value('(AbcName/text())[1]','varchar(30)') as Name,
  x2.n.value('(Number/text())[1]','varchar(30)') as Number
FROM @xml.nodes('soap:Envelope/soap:Body/x:Abc/x:Def') x1(DEF)
CROSS APPLY (VALUES(
    CAST(N'<r>' + x1.DEF.value('text()[1]','nvarchar(max)') + '</r>' AS xml)
)) v(InnerXml)
CROSS APPLY v.InnerXml.nodes('r') x2(n);
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=26abbefd8517fc41c6983719fbf5f36b)